# Multiple filters in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

Theres is a part of my application where i can specify some filters to retrieve certain data. But not all the filters are necessary so i can left some of them empty and the query just wouldn't use them. How can i achieve this in mongoDB. Thanks in advance.

client-side:

```
        $('#filter').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var filters = JSON.stringify({ Marca : $('#Marca').val(), Modelo : $('#Modelo').val(), Fecha : $('#Fecha').val()});

            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: filters,
            url: '/filterFees',
            contentType: 'application/json'
            }).done(function( response ) {
                if(response.msg === ''){
                    filterFees(response.data);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
                }
            })
        })
```

node.js(using monk):

```
app.post('/filterFees', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('Fees');

  collection.find({'Marca' : req.body.Marca, 'Modelo' : req.body.Modelo, 'Fecha' : req.body.Fecha, },{},function(err,docs){
        res.send((err === null) ? { msg: '', data : docs } : { msg:'error: ' + err });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if there the value exists in the filters

```
var filter = {}, filters;
if $('#Marca').val()
    filter.Marca = $('#Marca').val();

if $('#Modelo').val()
    filter.Modelo = $('#Modelo').val();

if $('#Fecha').val()
    filter.Fecha = $('#Fecha').val()

filters = JSON.stringify(filter);
```

and find data where filters

```
collection.find(req.body,{},function(err,docs){
    res.send((err === null) ? { msg: '', data : docs } : { msg:'error: ' + err });
});
```

PS. not sure why you stringify the parameters
instead of sending object

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!. I use the  `JSON.stringify()` because of the `contentType`. Otherwise i get an error 400 (Bad Request).